# Comparing one record value with other and finding the difference in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

Can anyone help me out how to write Pig script for the following requirement?
Imagine 1,2,3,4 are days and 100,120 etc are representing the distance travelled till date.Problem is how to find out the distance travelled per day using Pig script?

Input File:

```
1    100
2    120
3    165
4    193
```

Expected output:

```
1   100   
2   20
3   45
4   28
```

appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code:
data = load 'dataa' using PigStorage() as (seq:int, value:int);

firstrow = filter data by seq == 1;

newdata = foreach data generate seq + 1 as newseq, value as newval;
joined = join data by seq, newdata by newseq;
remainingrows = foreach joined generate data::seq as seq, data::value - newdata::newval as value;

out = union firstrow, remainingrows;
dump out;

This code works as long as first column consists of unique numbers. If such a provision is not there then a map-reduce program is to be used to generate numbers and then apply the same logic.